# TensorFlow on Windows: "not a supported wheel on this platform" error

Tags: tensorflow

Was happy to know Tensorflow is made available for Windows and we don't have to use Docker.

I tried to install as per instructions but I get this error.

> pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-0.12.0rc0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
>   tensorflow-0.12.0rc0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

What does that error mean?

I am running latest version of Python.

> python --version
>   Python 3.5.2

Comment: The all next of you, you have a really good guide here: http://www.netinstructions.com/how-to-install-tensorflow-on-windows-without-docker-or-virtual-machines/

Comment: I'm not able to comment on @mike answer but the updated and correct answer for me is that I had python 3.7 and tensorflow is currently only available for 3.5 and 3.6.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is most likely to be a 64-bit versus 32-bit issue. The pre-built TensorFlow pip package is 64-bit only, but the default version of Python 3.5.2 on Python.org is 32-bit. You can download the 64-bit release from [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-352/) (select one of the "Windows x86-64" options).

Comment: it works perfectly for me thanks, works also if we are using Anaconda

Comment: I have similar problem but as I checked my python version is 64-bit and yet problems still arise. Can you give some advise on this?

Comment: ya I did, the problem was the python version in Anaconda. So try change your python version to 3.5.2. try this.    > conda search python         make sure there is version 3.5.2               > conda install python=3.5.2

Comment: I had this similar issue but what ended up working was simply to change "35" to "36" in the wheel (I left everything else the same).

Answer (score 14):

It's only available for Python 3.5.x not 3.6.

You can quickly create a 3.5 environment with: 
conda create -n tensorflow python=3.5

Comment: Do you know why this is the case?

Answer (score 3):

You must have a 3.5.x version of Python. The 3.6 version won't work.
If you have installed an Anaconda that contains Python 3.6, you need to downgrade its Python to 3.5.2.

Open the **Anaconda Prompt** as administrator, and run:

```
conda install python=3.5.2
```

After the installation is finished, you can follow the rest of the steps on [tensorflow website](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows).

Answer (score 1):

Do you have Python and Anaconda installed? I had a similar issue until I uninstalled Anaconda and then the setup was fine.

Comment: This is not an answer. This is a comment.

Answer (score 1):

I did the following steps and it worked.(Anaconda 4.4 x64)

1- Go to Windows 10 command prompt (right click and Run as admin)
2- if activated the path, you can run conda anywhere, if not, should go to .../anaconda3/scripts and run conda command from there and do the following (the main trick was to change 35 to 36)
1- conda -n tensorflow python=3.5
2- activate tensorflow
3- pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-0.12.0rc0-cp3**6**-cp3**6**m-win_amd64.whl

Answer (score 0):

issues fixed when i did the downgrading from 3.6 to 3.5 using the below
conda install python=3.5.2

Answer (score 0):

There can be two reasons:

1) You are using 32-Bit python package. Tensorflow does not support 32 bit, only 64 fit. 
   Check in your system settings for this. If this is fine refer to second point..

2)You are using Python 3.7. 
  Python 3.7 isn't eventually officially supported by Python. It's still in beta testing, 
  and very much under active development.

Consider downgrading to a lower version of python. For now, stick with Python 3.6 or 3.5.