# Tensorflow installation on Windows 10, error 'Not a supported wheel on this platform'

Tags: windows, python-3.x, cmd, tensorflow

This question is for a Windows 10 laptop. I'm currently trying to install tensorflow, however, when I run:

`pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.0.0-cp35-cp35m-win_x86_64.whl`

I get the following error:

`tensorflow-1.0.0-cp35-cp35m-win_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`

I am trying to install the cpu-version only of tensorflow in an Anaconda 4.3.0 version. I had python 3.6.0 and then I downgraded to 3.5.0, none of them worked.

Comment: Have you tried solutions mentioned on other questions? Like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40941678/4638103) one?

Comment: Yes, my python is 64 bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also had same problem when I installed anaconda 4.3 version

Here is my solution.

- Instead of using Anaconda3 4.3, install Anaconda3 4.2(Anaconda3-4.2.0-Windows-x86_64.exe)
- Type on command line(If you are using GPU version)

  ```
  pip install -U --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-1.0.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
  ```
- Typeon command line(If you are using CPU only)

  ```
  pip install -U --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.0.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
  ```

I'm working on win10 with python version=3.5.2, 64 bit

Answer (score 2):

You can use same version of anaconda and execute this command

```
conda create -n tensorflow python=3.5
activate tensorflow
pip install tensorflow-gpu
```

It worked for **conda 4.0.8**

Answer (score 0):

So are you sure you correctly downgraded your python? Run this command on command line `pip -V`. This should print the pip version and the python version.

Comment: I have pip 9.0.1 and python 3.5, I already had checked it with python --version. However, with pip -V it said as well python 3.5 and it said that I had pip 9.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Inside your Anaconda environment, try running this:

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```

This will do the job. The issue was discussed [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7552) also.

Here is the screenshot of how this helped me:

[image: pip install --upgrade tensorflow]

Comment: Tried that, says 'NoneValue' has no attribute 'splitlines'.

Comment: @AntonioLópezRuiz there was some error in the last release. I tried installing the latest nightly from http://ci.tensorflow.org/job/tensorflow-master-win-cmake-py/ and it woked fine then.

Answer (score 0):

If you have python3 on Windows insatalled, you can use the following command(non GPU):

pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-0.10.0-py3-none-any.whl

Worked for me.